# Cordova PushNotification of Undefined

Tags: cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, ngcordova

I have checked all the solutions for the same questions. But still can't solve the issue. I'm using visual studio and cordova application. 
Added the phonegap-plugin-push and corresponding code has been added. Using the ngCordova $cordovapushV5. Getting PushNotification of undefined error, i've checked in physical device and tried android version 5.1 and 6.2.1.
Added script files in below order.

```
 <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/ng-cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>


app.run(function ($http, $cordovaPushV5) {

        var options = {
            android: {
                senderID: "xxxxxx"
            },
            ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: "true",
                sound: "true"
            },
            windows: {}
        };

        // initialize
        $cordovaPushV5.initialize(options).then(function () {
            // start listening for new notifications
            $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
            // start listening for errors
            $cordovaPushV5.onError();

            // register to get registrationId
            $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function (registrationId) {
                // save `registrationId` somewhere;
            })
        });

        // triggered every time notification received
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function (event, data) {
            // data.message,
            // data.title,
            // data.count,
            // data.sound,
            // data.image,
            // data.additionalData
            alert(data.message);
        });

        // triggered every time error occurs
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:errorOcurred', function (event, e) {
            // e.message
            alert(e.message)
        });



});
```

Comment: Did you get any error or warnings when installing the plugin?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error

Comment: which version of push plugin are you used ?

Comment: @Hiten 2.0.0 version